# issue with consuming restful webservice from openweather Api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, restful-authentication, restful-url

i was trying to retreive weather details from openweathermap api , some how i am not able to get it working with below errors . Any help would be highly appreciated

Controller

```
@Controller
public class CurrentWeatherController {
 
    private final StubWeatherService stubWeatherService;
    private final LiveWeatherService liveWeatherService;
 
    public CurrentWeatherController(StubWeatherService stubWeatherService, LiveWeatherService liveWeatherService) {
        this.stubWeatherService = stubWeatherService;
        this.liveWeatherService = liveWeatherService;
    }
 
    @GetMapping("/current-weather")
    public String getCurrentWeather(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("currentWeather", liveWeatherService.getCurrentWeather("Detroit","us"));
        return "current-weather";
    }

    public StubWeatherService getStubWeatherService() {
        return stubWeatherService;
    }
```

service code

```
@Service
public class LiveWeatherService {

    private static final String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city},{country}&APPID={key}&units=metric";

    private final String apiKey="526a647fcd4f3f465c0340c19d26ef3a";

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public LiveWeatherService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public CurrentWeather getCurrentWeather(String city, String country) {
        URI url = new UriTemplate(WEATHER_URL).expand(city, country,this.apiKey);    // line 34 issue with accepting apikey 
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

        return convert(response);
    }

    private CurrentWeather convert(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
        try {
            JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(response.getBody());
            return new CurrentWeather(root.path("weather").get(0).path("main").asText(),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(root.path("main").path("temp").asDouble()),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(root.path("main").path("feels_like").asDouble()),
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(root.path("wind").path("speed").asDouble()));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing JSON", e);
        }
    }
}
```

error

> 2-07 02:34:48.710 ERROR 43384 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error:
> Unresolved compilation problem:
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from UriTemplate to URI
> ] with root cause
>
> ```
> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from UriTemplate to URI
>
>   at com.meshupProjekt.service.LiveWeatherService.getCurrentWeather(LiveWeatherService.java:34)
> ```
>
> ~[classes/:na]
> at com.meshupProjekt.controller.CurrentWeatherController.getCurrentWeather(CurrentWeatherController.java:36)
> ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-

Answer (score 0):

For me your code is working like this:

```
    String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city},{country}&APPID={key}&units=metric";
    String apiKey = "526a647fcd4f3f465c0340c19d26ef3a";
    var x = new UriTemplate(WEATHER_URL).expand("Darmstadt", "Deutschland", apiKey);
    System.out.println(x);
```

Instead of `URI` I used `var` so that Java selects proper type.
Your compilation error might be caused by wrong import of `URI` class.